# Coding Style - Clean Architecture and Helpers

Tags: clean-architecture

I'm learning golang and decided to give it a go (pun mildly intended) with a side project that I had in mind for some time (though question is probably language agnostic).

I decided to learn more about the [clean architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) along the way because I learnt the hard way about having a bad architecture in the current project I'm dealing with in my day job.

Here is a simplified layout of relevant part of my project:

```
.
└── app
    ├── error_codes
    │   └── error_codes.go
    ├── interfaces
    │   └── interfaces.go
    ├── models
    │   └── repo
    │       └── repo.go
    ├── managers
    │   └── vcs_managers
    │       └── git_manager
    │           └── git_manager.go
    └── helpers
        └── helpers.go
```

Now `error_codes`, `interfaces` and `models` are all in the innermost circle of the architecture.

Here is where I'm getting confused. On my `Repo` model, I have some functions that does stuff and doing that stuff requires some helper methods in `helpers` package. But as per the requirements of clean architecture, I cannot refer to helpers package from Repo model, because of the direction of the dependency.

I feel like I'm missing something really fundamental. What am I missing in this picture?

Comment: you should probably avoid "helpers" completely and instead figure out where this code actually belongs to. if it is about business logic why not putting it into the innermost circle?

Comment: These are functions like transforms a unix-style path to a windows style path, or things like returns type of host os. So they don't actually belong to any of my business logics. Besides they heavily depend on certain golang libraries, which I presume something  not allowed in the innermost circle.

Comment: @plainionist OMG are you this plainionist? :D 
http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Overview/

I've just started to read your articles today :)

Comment: yes that's me ;-) Hope u find these articles helpful. Regarding your question: from my perspective these helpers most probably should belong to "interface adapters" and should be used from application logic via "dependency inversion" (e.g. interfaces)